# cast UIButton from cell to run a query and send results to another cell

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

i'm querying data from a VC and sending the output to another VC that has a TableViewCell. with the results in the cell, i'm trying to run another query to Firebase and display the results in another VC that has a custom prototype cell. i'm able to manually run the queries in both instances, my issue(confusion) is how to call the IBAction button to run the query. I dont know how to cast the cell to run the query and performSegue to the thirdVC

**mainVC**

```
@IBAction func getDataPressed(_ sender: Any) {
     query......
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "cell1" {
       let vc = segue.destination as! secondVC
       vc.data = data
       self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "cell1", sender: self)
    }
}
```

**secondVC**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: 
    Int) -> Int {
    return info.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
    "secondVcCell", for: indexPath)
    as? secondVcCell {
    cell.configureCell(inf: info[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}

return UITableViewCell()
```

**CustomCellDelegate**

```
protocol CustomCellDelegate {
         func callSegueFromcell(_ sender: Any?)
```

**secondVcCell**

```
var delegate: CustomeCellDelegate?
@IBOutlet weak var cellBtn: UIButton 



@IBAction func getDataPressed2(_ sender: Any) {
  query ........
}
     if(self.delegate !=nil)
     self.delegate.callSegueFromcell(Any)
```

**thirdVC**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: 
Int) -> Int {
return info2.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:    "thirdVcCell", 
for: indexPath)
    as? ThirdVcCell {
    cell.configureCell(inf1: info2[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}

return UITableViewCell()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. for the query, just call the function for querying in the IBAction button by typing the function within the range.
2. for the second cast if you are pulling from firebase then you will need to change your code to include firebase DataBase or Firestore, if you are taking it manually then you need to do the same as the first cast but make sure the indexPath is correct

Comment: yes, i'm pulling from Firebase but my problem is that when i click the Button that is inside the SecondVcCell to pull data and perform segue to the thirdVC, the segue does not work.

Comment: @David run some else statements for your if statements and do a print("failed at ...") to see where it fails

Comment: i apologize, i've been out of commission. When i do the print("failed at...\(String(describing: error))") i get that the delegate is NIL. I'm going to update my code with the updates. thx